# Find the limit. Given that the function is continuous on [0,1] how could we find it?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_{0}^{1} x^{n} f(x)dx$$ could there be any generalisation for the powers of the form $$n^k$$ instead of n within the limit of the integral ? how could we find it? I tried to use the fact that f being continuous on the compact it is bounded but that would work if wr hadnt had that n in front of the integrand

Comment: I remember that the result was f(1) but how to prove that?

Comment: Hint: Use the substitution $u=x^{n+1}$

Comment: Show that the limit gives $f(1)$ whenever $f(x)$ is a power of $x$. Then by linearity of the integral (and limit), the property will hold for any polynomial. Then by density (Stone-Weierstrass theorem), the property will hold for continuous function.

Comment: I will try, those ideas are new for me such as linearity and density

Comment: It s clear that for x->x^k the limit is f(1)=1 in this situation

Comment: I'd like an elementary proof, please

Comment: Mathematicians would usually like complicated proofs so that they could learn new things. Sometimes proofs from heavy theory come more elegant than those from elementary methods. Did you try to prove that dependance of your integral on values of your function in domain [0,1-eps] vanish as n goes to infinity? That way you can get that the result depends only on values in neighbourhood of 1, but you will still need a lot of rigour to justify such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  For this $\varepsilon$, fix the number $\delta>0$ such that whenever $1-\delta<x\le 1$, $|f(x)-f(1)|<\varepsilon$.

Then, we have the estimates

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 nx^n (f(x)-f(1))\,dx\right|&\le \int_0^{1-\delta}nx^n \left|f(x)-f(1)\right|\,dx+\int_{1-\delta}^1 nx^n \left|f(x)-f(1)\right|\,dx\\\\
&\le 2||f||_{\infty}\frac n{n+1}\left(1-\delta\right)^{n+1}+\varepsilon \frac n{n+1}\left(1-\delta^{n+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

Let $n\to \infty$ and conclude.